# Get the result of the select statement and put it in the variable. C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, c#-4.0, ms-access

I have a code that gets the name from the database. The code is below.

```
public void Get_lastname()
    {
        string abc = null;
        connstring.Open();
       OleDbCommand get_lastname = new OleDbCommand("SELECT lastname FROM tbltransactionhistory where name LIKE '" + txtname.Text + "'", connstring);
       get_lastname.ExecuteNonQuery();           
       connstring.Close();
     }
```

I not that good in T-Sql statements, I want to know is it possible for me to get the result of the Select Statement and put it in the abc variable? Thanks guys

Comment: Use sqldataadapter or sqldatareader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExecuteScalar()` method.

Also, do not concatenate strings, use parameters.

Plus, you can use `using` structure for opening a connection to make sure it's always closed properly:

```
string abc = null;
using (OleDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand get_lastname = new OleDbCommand("SELECT lastname FROM tbltransactionhistory where name LIKE @name", conn);
    get_lastname.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
    abc = (string)get_lastname.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: One thing sir. the Code  
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
I get an error. How can I solve this?

Comment: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.OleDbConnection(string)' has some invalid arguments"

and 

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' to 'string'

Comment: Put your connection string where `connstring` is in the code above.